# How to change the color of just one header in a telerik grid?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik-grid

I am working on a telerik radgrid with five columns. I want the header of just one column to be of some specific color. The Column is declared in the following format:

```
items.Add().Text("Incidents").Content(() =>
```

How can I add a style for changing the color in the given snippet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use something like:

```
"radGrid.Columns[1].HeaderStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#ffea77");
```